# Download Symbols from Microsoft

Tags: c#, debugging

I am following this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/11/intro-to-windbg-for-net-developers.aspx )and it is saying download symbols from Microsoft from this address, but I could not find them... can you help with that please? thanks.

is it where I should go to download them? http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Comment: You don't actually download them manually, you set the symbol path in the windbg, "File" -> "Choose Symbol Path" -> input `srv*d:\debug\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`. It says that further down in the article.

Comment: @pjumble you should add this as an answer.

Comment: In some versions of WinDbg you can also write `.symfix+ d:\debug\symbols`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you debugging? In Visual Studio 2010 you can just right click on the offending stack frame and download the symbols from there:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: Didn't know about this feature of VS2010, thought symbols had to be loaded the way it was done in 08 so thanks for a good tip...